# sklearn BallTree giving unexpected results

Tags: python, scikit-learn

What am I doing wrong?

I am trying to use sklearn's BallTree in order to come up with similar collections and then generate some suggestions on items that might be missing from a given collection.

```
import random
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import numpy

collections = []  # 10k sample collections of between
                  # 7 and 15 (of a possible 300...) items

for sample in range(0, 10000):  # build sample data
   items = random.sample(range(1, 300), random.randint(7, 15))
   collections.append(items)    

darray = numpy.zeros((len(collections), max(map(len, collections))))  # 10k x 15 matrix

for c_cnt, items in enumerate(collections):  # populate matrix
   for cnt, i in enumerate(sorted(items)):
      darray[C_cnt][cnt] = i

query = BallTree(darray).query(darray[0], k=15)

nearest_neighbors = query[1][0]

# test the results against the first item!

all_sets = [set(darray[0]) & set(darray[item]) for item in nearest_neighbors]
for item in all_sets:
    print item  # intersection of the neighbor
```

I get the following results:

```
set([0.0, 130.0, 167.0, 290.0, 162.0, 144.0, 17.0, 214.0]) # Nearest neighbor is itself! Awesome!
set([0.0])  # WTF? The second closest item shares only 1 item?
set([0.0, 290.0])
set([0.0, 17.0])
set([0.0, 130.0])
set([0.0])
set([0.0])
set([0.0])
set([0.0])
set([0.0])
set([0.0])
set([0.0])
set([0.0, 162.0])
set([0.0, 144.0, 162.0])  # uhh okay, i would expect this to be higher up
set([0.0, 144.0, 17.0])
```

I observe that the higher suggested items tend to have the same length of non-zero values as the array I am attempting to compare. Is there some preparation I can do with my data to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

By default the BallTree computes the Euclidean distance between your vectors, and so it is inappropriate for the type of computation you have in mind.

As a simple example, imagine you have the following two sets:

```
collections[0] = [1, 3]
collections[1] = [1, 2, 3]
```

When you convert them to vectors within `darray` as you have done above, they become this:

```
darray[0] = [1, 3, 0]
darray[1] = [1, 2, 3]
```

The Euclidean distance between these does not reflect the number of similar entries in the set, which is why the results are not what you expected.

Rather than a Euclidean distance, the distance metric you're looking for is probably the [Jaccard distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index), which measures the similarity between sets. The BallTree implements this for Boolean representations of the sets; that is, for the above data the vectors would become

```
darray[0] = [True, False, True]
darray[1] = [True, True, True]
```

where the first entry indicates if `1` is in the set, the second entry indicates if `2` is in the set, and so on. This is a version of "one-hot encoding".

For the sample data you provided, you can compute the results this way:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

# for replicability
np.random.seed(0)

# Compute the collections using a more efficient method
collections = [np.random.choice(300, replace=False,
                                size=np.random.randint(7, 15))
               for _ in range(10000)]

# Use DictVectorizer to compute binary representation of collections
dicts = [dict(zip(c, np.ones_like(c))) for c in collections]
darray = DictVectorizer(sparse=False, dtype=bool).fit_transform(dicts)

# Compute 15 nearest neighbors for the first collection
dist, ind = BallTree(darray, metric='jaccard').query(darray[0], k=15)
for i in ind[0]:
    print(set(collections[0]) & set(collections[i]))
```

I get the following results:

```
{225, 226, 261, 166, 296, 52, 150, 246, 215, 221, 223}
{52, 261, 221, 215}
{225, 226, 166, 150}
{223, 150, 215}
{225, 261, 166, 221}
{226, 261, 223}
{261, 150, 221}
{223, 52, 166, 215}
{296, 226, 166, 223}
{296, 221, 150}
{223, 52, 215}
{52, 261, 246}
{296, 225, 52}
{296, 225, 221}
{225, 150, 223}
```

Note that the Jaccard similarity is not simply the size of the intersection, but that size normalized by the size of the union. The size of the intersection alone does not have the properties of a distance metric, and so cannot be computed directly with the BallTree.

Edit: I should add that if you have many entries in the sets, this method becomes untenable because the boolean encoding matrix becomes too large. The best way to compute very high-dimensional neighbor searches with the Jaccard distance is probably via Locality Sensitive Hashing, though I don't know of an easy-to-use Python implementation suitable for this problem.